# Delete Query from codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how I need to do this query. I'm trying to delete all the users who have registered but not activated witin a certain time limit.

```
function purgeNA($expirePeriod)
{
    $this->db->where('usersStatusesID', 1);
    $this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(registrationDate) <', time() - $expirePeriod);
    $this->db->delete($this->usersRegistrationsTable);
}
```

Here's my db structure:

```
usersRegistrationsTable - userID, registrationDate
usersTable              - userID, usersStatusesID
```

Comment: Do you want deletions from `usersTable` and `usersRegistrationsTable`?  or only `usersTable`?

Comment: Both tables that way the person will have to reregister if its passed a certain time.

Comment: Check for foreign key constraints and the database structure, if the foreign key gets delete on deletion of primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, codeigniter doesn't support `JOIN`s in `DELETE` queries via the Active Record interface. Instead, you'll need to execute a SQL statement:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM 
          usersTable u
          JOIN usersRegistrationsTable r ON u.userID = r.userID
          WHERE usersStatusesID = 1 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(registrationDate) < ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(time() = $expirePeriod));
```